# Group by and select rows based on if value combinations exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a table `PetsTable`:

| Id | Type | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Cat" | 10 | 5 |
| 1 | "Cat" | 9 | 2 |
| 2 | "dog" | 10 | 5 |
| 1 | "Cat" | 8 | 4 |
| 1 | "Cat" | 6 | 3 |
| 2 | "dog" | 8 | 4 |
| 2 | "dog" | 6 | 3 |
| 3 | "Cat" | 13 | 5 |
| 3 | "Cat" | 10 | 0 |
| 3 | "Cat" | 8 | 0 |

How to insert this data into a new table `MyPets` from `PetsTable` with these conditions:

- Group by Id
- Only select rows when in the group exists (key = 10 and value = 5) and (key = 8 and value = 4) and (key = 6 and value = 3)
- If exists key = 9, then mark hasFee = 1 else hasFee = 0

Final table should look like:

| Id | Type | hasFee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "Cat" | 1 |
| 2 | "dog" | 0 |

Comment: I am stuck on how to  select rows based on if value combinations exist, in this case. I am totally new to SQL

Comment: Yes, I need to create an actual table in the database.

Comment: You are right, create the table as a separate action , and then just insert into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use window functions to evaluate your conditions, which you can then apply as conditions using a CTE.

This creates the data you desire, its then trivial to insert into a table of your choice.

```
create table Test (Id int, [Type] varchar(3), [Key] int, [Value] int);

insert into Test (Id, [Type], [Key], [Value])
values
(1, 'Cat', 10, 5),
(1, 'Cat', 9,  2),
(2, 'Dog', 10, 5),
(1, 'Cat', 8,  4),
(1, 'Cat', 6,  3),
(2, 'Dog', 8,  4),
(2, 'Dog', 6,  3),
(3, 'Cat', 13, 5),
(3, 'Cat', 10, 0),
(3, 'Cat', 8,  0);

with cte as (
  select *
    , sum(case when [Key] = 10 and [Value] = 5 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Id) Cond1
    , sum(case when [Key] = 8 and [Value] = 4 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Id) Cond2
    , sum(case when [Key] = 6 and [Value] = 3 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Id) Cond3
    , sum(case when [Key] = 9 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by Id) HasFee
  from Test
)
select Id, [Type], HasFee
from cte
where Cond1 = 1 and Cond2 = 1 and Cond3 = 1
group by Id, [Type], HasFee;
```

Returns:

| Id | Type | HasFee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat | 1 |
| 2 | Dog | 0 |

Note: If you provide your sample data in this format (DDL+DML) you make it *much* easier for people to assist.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OZfn08yf)

Comment: Thank you for the help and feedback. I will keep it in mind for future.